# I am unable to understand the meaning of this line of code while working with Beautiful Soup module

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

```
def search(self, topic, site):
        bs = self.getPage(site.searchurl + topic)
        searchresults = bs.select(site.resultingList)
        for result in searchresults:
            url = result.select(site.resulturl)[0].attrs["href"]
            if (site.absoluteUrl):
                bs = self.getPage(url)
            else:
                bs = self.getPage(site.url + url)
            if bs is None:
                print("Something was wrong with that page or URL. Skipping!")
                return
            title = self.safeGet(bs, site.titleTag)
            body = self.safeGet(bs, site.bodyTag)
            if title != '' and body != '':
                content = Content(topic, title, body, url)
                content.print()
```

In this code what is the meaning of:

```
result.select(site.resulturl)[0].attrs["href"]
```

more specifically, i'm unable to understand `attrs["href"]`

Answer (score 1):

`attrs["href"]` pulls the "href" attribute from `result.select(site.resulturl)[0]`. So most likely `site.resulturl` contains at least 1 or more `<a ... href="...">` tags (or any other tag that has an "href" attribute), and that line is pulling the link out of the first one in the list.